# Could not resolve in adding HMS Huawei repos in gradle

Tags: java, android, huawei-mobile-services

im trying to integrate in HMS Huawei, in adding classpath im have error:

> Could not resolve com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.6.0.300.

my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {url 'https://developer.huawei.com/repo/'}
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
        classpath 'com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.6.0.300'
    }
}



allprojects {
    repositories {

        google()
        jcenter()
        repositories {
            maven { url  'http://dl.bintray.com/swallowsonny/ext/' }
            maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
            maven { url 'https://developer.huawei.com/repo/' }
        }

    }
}
```

my gradle ver: 6.7.1 and gradle plugin ver: 4.1.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Go to **File** -> **Project Settings** -> **Gradle** and uncheck the Gradle offline work option.

Synchronize the project again and let all the dependencies get downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

I have corrected settings.gradle like this:

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven {url 'https://developer.huawei.com/repo/'} // add this line
    }
}
```